# I would like to receive the ID value of checked Opportunity Product within Opportunity and process it

Tags: related-list, opportunity-lineitem

[image]

We tried to get the ID value of the checked Opportunity Product in the Opportunity record and process it as Button. However, OpportunityLIneItem does not support StandardController on VisualforcePage. How can I get that checked record ID?

Comment: What do you need it for? Is it for Apex? Can a custom list button help there?

Comment: Yes, I tried to process it as list button, but OpportunityLineItem does not support Standard Controller. So what should I do to get the ID value of the checked record in the Related List?